# Команда модуля shutil для добавления в архив новых директорий

Tags: python, shutil

у меня такой вопрос, я хочу сделать архиватор, который спрашивает у пользователя какие папки он хочет архивировать? Но я не нашёл команды, которая будет создавать не новый архив, а добавлять в этот архив новую папку. То есть при введение каждой последней директории архив перезаписывается, можно ли это как то реализовать самому? Или может всё таки есть команда для пополнения архива?

```
import os
import time 
import shutil

# получение имени папки(время создания):
time_s = time.time() # получение времени с начала эпохи в секундах
time_y = time.ctime(time_s) # преобразование секунд в нормальное время

# замена недопустимых символов
time_y = time_y.replace(" ", "_") 
time_y = time_y.replace(":", ".") 

# создание папки
directory = os.getcwd() # получаем местоположение программы
dir_res = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(directory), time_y) #создание правильного пути к папке с программой



# сбор имён требуемых для архивации файлов

list_dir = ["E:/Educ", "E:/CFG"]

for i in list_dir:
    shutil.make_archive(dir_res, "zip", i, i)

close = str(input("Нажмите любую кнопку для завершения..."))
```

Или может мне следует использовать иной модуль для моей задачи?

Comment: shutil дает только базовую поддержку архивов, для модификации уже имеющихся архивов (добавление, удаление файлов и т.п.) можно использовать модуль [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html).

Comment: спасибо большое